# using Number as mask, iMask automatically modifies the input when field is blurred

Tags: numbers, min, mask, imaskjs

const    opts =  {
lazy: true,
autofix: false,
min:100 ,
max:9999999,
mask: Number,
thousandsSeparator: ' ',
scale: 0,
}
}

With the above setup, if I enter 50 and then focus on another input, the value will be automatically adjusted to 100 (the min). This is unacceptable because the user might have not idea of the change.

I have tried to undo the change effected by iMask, but it won't let me. The only solution I can think of is to intercept and prevent the onblur event handler set up by iMask, but I have been unsuccessful.